# setTimeout still fires despite clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have the following function. The intent is that when you hover over an item with the class `.toolTip`, it'll log the `data-tooltip` from the element you're hovering over after 3 seconds. However, if your cursor leaves the item, it should cancel the setTimeout and not show the message.

The "Timeout set" and "Timeout cleared" messages fire as expected, but the named function fires anyway. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).on("hover",".toolTip", function() {
    var toolTip = $(this);
    var toolTipMessage
    var hoveringNow = toolTip.attr("data-hovering-now");
    if(typeof hoveringNow !== typeof undefined && hoveringNow !== false) {
        toolTip.removeAttr('data-hovering-now');
        clearTimeout(toolTipMessage);
        console.log('Timeout cleared');
    }
    else {
        toolTip.attr('data-hovering-now', true);
        toolTipMessage = setTimeout(showToolTip, 3000, toolTip.attr("data-tooltip"));
        console.log('Timeout set');
    }               
});

function showToolTip(message) {
    console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: Put `var toolTipMessage` outside the `hover` function handler, otherwise you redefine it on each event. I'm also a little confused as to the point of the `hovering-now` data attribute to retain the state, why not just use the two handler functions? One for mouseenter and the other for mouseleave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `toolTipMessage` only lives within the execution context of the function which is executed on hover, by the next time you hover that element, the variable no longer exists (or, more exactly you have a *different* variable of the same name).

For the variable to persist between executions, you need that variable defined in an enclosing execution context - such as outside the `hover` handler.

```
var toolTipMessage = null;
$(document).on("hover",".toolTip", function() {
   ....
});
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks, that makes perfect sense now that you've said it.

Comment: Different `execution context` is the term i believe.